# PHP Fatal Error when tried to acces object

Tags: php, fatal-error

I have the following code :

```
$member = unserialize($data['member']);
$_SESSION['inscription'] = $this->getLink('inscription/login='.$member->getEmail()
```

I have the error :

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getEmail() on a non-object

What can be the cause?

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($member);` ? (BTW: Missing semicolon + bracket at the end.)

Comment: Your $member variable is definitely not an object.

Comment: The problem is tha the error is in production, and I can test this on dev

Comment: what is the output of $member? can you update your answer with that.

Comment: If `$member` will become `false`, please also ensure that the class of `$member` is available (included) when calling `unserialize` so that the object can be restored from the serialized object.